# How to submit linked models using DjangoRestFramework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In continuation to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16429160/how-to-serialize-into-multiple-models-using-djangorestframework) question, can you please give an example of a valid input json to simultaneously create a new User and UserProfile?

While this successfully creates a new user on **User** end-point:

```
{
    "username": "newuser", 
    "password": "abc"
}
```

But this **fails** on **UserProfile** end-point:

```
{
    "user":{
            "username": "newuser2", 
            "password": "abc"
    }
    "biography": "1",
}
```

Returning:

```
{
    "user": [
        "This field cannot be null."
    ]
}
```

Comment: Usually these take a resource uri pointing to another resource for related objects but I can't say for sure that DjangoRestFramework does since I haven't used it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is read+**write** support for nested resources which will [soon be supported](http://django-rest-framework.org/topics/2.3-announcement.html#what-comes-next), but is not as of yet.

However, if you link your user profile model to the user model with a  [`HyperlinkedRelatedField`](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations.html#hyperlinkedrelatedfield) you could first create a user and then create a user profile with the created user's URI as user argument. Assuming you have the following user profile model and serializer::

```
# Model:
class UserProfile(models.Model):
country = models.CharField(max_length=127)
wants_newsletter = models.BooleanField(default=False)

# Serializer:
class UserProfile(serializers.ModelSerializer):
user = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField('user-detail')

class Meta:
    fields = ('country', 'wants_newsletter')
```

... and a user object at `users/1/`, you could create a new user profile for the given user with the following POST request to the user profile endpoint::

```
{
    "country": "Switzerland",
    "user": "/users/1/"
}
```

If that's too many requests for you, take a a look at [the docs](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers.html#deserializing-multiple-objects-for-creation).